# webjob failing / file not found exception / Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: azure-webjobs

I'm pretty sure I understand the error, I just don't understand why and why now.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Sure enough the version the web site is: [image: Properties of existing file from directory of the web job]

My question is that this was a running web job which ran successfully back in 2018-09-03 - why is it failing on the versioning of an assembly now?

[image: Last time it ran]

After this time, we simply turned down the resources of the web site, and waiting for the next time the system would be used.

This year, I cranked up the resources and it's now failing!  The Web.config has no reference to this file or the version - so I'm thinking it should just find the dll, but I don't know why it's referring to the 9.3.0.0 version, and why the reference to the 7.2.1.0 version?

I really don't want to take the time to re-deploy and recompile, as that will then require a full regression test - and the client will simply not pay for something that should just be running.

What am I missing?

Comment: "we simply turned down the resources of the web site, and waiting for the next time the system would be used." what do you mean by that? Was the resource (WebApp) dealocated and a new WebApp was created later?

Comment: I wonder if "cranked up the resources" was re-deploying with newer WebApp version that referenced a newer SDK, hence depending on the newer Azure Storage version.

Comment: scale up, and scale down - that was it.  Its an application service so it can't be deallocated like a VM can

Comment: I'd raise a support issue with Azure. This should not be happening.